# Program “make” is not found in path in Eclipse-ADT

Tags: java, android, c++, cross-platform, cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos2d-x. When I am opening hello.cpp project in Eclipse-ADT it is giving me the error (program "make" is not found in path).

I have followed this Link.

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_set_up_the_android_cocos2d-x_development_environment_on_Windows_7

Image is also attached ...

[image]

Comment: please edit your original question rather than posting a new question (original: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796366/program-make-is-not-found-in-path-in-eclipse-adt)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D It seems the question has been removed.

Comment: yup, by its author ;) Deleting the original question works too in this case.

Answer (score 0):

make is a linux command, you need to run it under linux or install Cygwin to be able to run it on windows (make is under Devel package during Cygwin installation)

Comment: I have also installed Cygwin (autoconf, automake, binutils, gcc-core, gcc-g++, gcc4-core, gcc4-g++, gdb, pcre, pcre-devel, gawk, [make] ) packages as in the description link. Cygwin terminal is also working.

Comment: Yes i have done that too.

Waqas Majeed@VIETTEL-6C4DF47 ~
$ make -v
GNU Make 4.0
Built for i686-pc-cygwin
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Comment: did you add your Cygwin\bin directory to your PATH environment variable?

Comment: Going into the properties of My Computer -> Advanced -> Enviroment variables?
or
c/c++ builder -> builder setting -> Enviroment?

Comment: properties of My Computer, as the compiler runs default command prompt for your OS and tryes to issue make -v there, if you dont set it in your PATH variable its unable to find the command

Comment: I have added this to path varriable
C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools;C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools;

in My Computer -> Advanced -> Enviroment variables -> path

Comment: okey, but does the command make -v runs in your windows command line?

Comment: Waqas Majeed@VIETTEL-6C4DF47 ~
($ type g++)
[g++ is /usr/bin/g++]

Waqas Majeed@VIETTEL-6C4DF47 ~
($ type make)
[make is /usr/bin/make]

BTW it is in Cygwin Terminal.

Comment: You have to add the NDK path in built_native.sh file              #paths                                                      NDK_ROOT=""

Comment: @Mac_Focha
 no cmd isn't recognizing make -v .
(make in not recognized as an internal or external command, aperable program or batch file.)

Comment: @SumitKandoi Can you explain please.

Comment: If your project is not compiling then you have to add the NDK PATH in it

Comment: then theres your problem, you need to investigate why is that happening. first check whether any simple command (like ls) is recognisable, if yes, navigate to cygwin/bin (also in command prompt) and try issue make -v from there, tell me the results

Comment: Is this because of windows XP? Is it compatible to XP?

Comment: i doubt its win Xp problem, it should be compatible. Did you perform those things i mentioned? results?

Comment: I wasn't able to fix that on windows . So, My Boss gave me a Mac :P :)

Answer (score 0):

finally found it.

open Eclipse.

go to **Window->Preferences**

go to **C/C++->New CDT Project Wizard->Makefile Project**

check "**Cygwin PE Parser**" and "**GNU Elf Parser**"

in both manually set the path to those commands you see below each one.

for example select "Cygwin PE Parser" and click Browse button of the "cygpath command"
and find cygpath.exe file inside "bin" folder of the cygwin.

mine is like this:
"C:\Users\MDP\Cygwin\bin\cygpath.exe"

do the same thing for all of them. and click apply then ok.

remove your project and add it again. 
you won't get these errors anymore:

**program "make" is not found in path**

**Program "bash" not found in PATH**